# What is the universe and the multiverse and how do you use them in the synaptic package manager

Tags: synaptic

I have recently installed the synaptic package manager and there are various options  related to the universe and the multiverse in it. what exactly are they and how do you you use the Synaptic package manager with them

Answer (score 0):

Here is a screenshot of the 'Software & Updates' window (part of Ubuntu's default software setup):

[image]

- The **main** repository is the *main* software for Ubuntu, and is officially supported by Canonical ([Ubuntu's parent company](https://www.ubuntu.com/community/canonical))
- **Universe** has open-source programs that can be used in Ubuntu, supported by the Ubuntu & linux community.
- **Multiverse** includes video codecs, encrypted DVD streamers etc, which may not be open-source, and/or may cause legal problems.
- **Restricted** - Closed-source drivers

You can also add other repositories/[PPAs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) to download packages from (though please check if you can trust the source of the compiled software!!). Sometimes these are included in packages for updating them - e.g. for Google Chrome, Spotify.

More information can be found on [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu).